# postgresql text search in json column with knex.js

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm using the postgresql in node application with knex.js

I want to search for a value that is present in the JSON column

I'm able to do the same in posgresql but unable to find any equivalant in knex.js

```
select * from <table_name> where <json_column_name>::text like '%search_value%'
```